# change the shape of a kernel of a convolution layer in keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

if i have a kernel size of 3X3, it will look at one pixel around the pixel it is focused on.
for example, for the kernel:

```
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9
```

it will use 1-9 to produce a value at location 5 at the feature map. 
is there a way to make it so that it will produce a value at location 9? so for each location at the feature map, it will only "see" the pixels on top and to left of it?

in keras, tensorflow backend.

EDIT:
based on the answer I got, I use the following code:

```
from keras.layers import Layer
class CornerConv2D(Layer):
    def __init__(self, filters, **kwargs):
        self.filters = filters
        self.kernel_size = (3,3)
        super(CornerConv2D, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        shape = self.kernel_size + (input_shape[-1], self.filters)
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='kernel', shape=shape,
                                  initializer='glorot_uniform')
        super(CornerConv2D, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, layer_input):

        custom_kernel = K.get_value(self.kernel)
        # set the bottom right corner as zero
        custom_kernel[-1,-1,:,:] = np.zeros_like(custom_kernel[-1,-1,:,:])

        return K.conv2d(layer_input,  custom_kernel)

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0], input_shape[1]-2, input_shape[1]-2) + (self.filters,)


inp = Input(shape=(64,64,1))
x = ZeroPadding2D(1)(inp)
x = CornerConv2D(30)(x)
x = ZeroPadding2D(1)(x)
x = CornerConv2D(30)(x)
x = ZeroPadding2D(1)(x)
x = CornerConv2D(1)(x)


m = Model(inputs=[inp], outputs=[x])

m.compile(loss='mse', optimizer="adam")

m.summary()
```

there is still a problem with this. while the model is created without a problem, and can predict without any errors, when I try to train it:

```
m.fit(imgs, imgs, batch_size=32, epochs=2)
```

it gives the error:

```
An operation has `None` for gradient. Please make sure that all of your ops have a gradient defined (i.e. are differentiable). Common ops without gradient: K.argmax, K.round, K.eval.
```

Comment: You can create a custom layer where the 3x3 kernel is replaced by 5x5 and 9 is at the center and rest of the weights (other than 1-9 at top left corner) are kept zero (mask it after every weight update or something similar). Also, may I ask why you need such functionality?

Comment: its an idea, but I could not find a good resource on how to build a custom layer in keras (the docs are very unclear for me). I need it for a degree project in image generation.

Comment: I ran your code and for me the output shape after one zeropadding and one cornerconv is the same as the input. 65,65,1 after zeropadding and back to 64,64,1 after cornerconv.

Comment: Ok, the error now is that one of the weights in the filter is unused so a gradient cannot be computed for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing your own layer where you manipulate the kernel and applying zero padding on left and top should achieve what you want:

```
             0  0  0  0 
1  2  3      0  1  2  3
4  5  6  ->  0  4  5  6 
7  8  9      0  7  8  9
```

And kernel will consider:

```
f  f
f  0
```

For position 4 it will only consider 1, for position 5 it will consider 1,2,4 and position 9 it will consider 5,6,8. You can tinker with padding as you wish.

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import ZeroPadding2D
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
import numpy as np

class CornerConv2D(Layer):
    def __init__(self, filters, **kwargs):
        self.filters = filters
        self.kernel_size = (2,2)
        super(CornerConv2D, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        shape = self.kernel_size + (input_shape[-1], self.filters)
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='kernel', shape=shape,
                                  initializer='glorot_uniform')
        super(CornerConv2D, self).build(input_shape)


    def call(self, layer_input):

        custom_kernel = K.get_value(self.kernel)
        # set the bottom right corner as zero
        custom_kernel[-1,-1,:,:] = np.zeros_like(custom_kernel[-1,-1,:,:])

        K.set_value(self.kernel, custom_kernel)
        return K.conv2d(layer_input,  self.kernel)


    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape[:-1] + (self.filters,)


m = Sequential()
m.add(ZeroPadding2D(((1, 0), (1, 0) ), input_shape=(9,9,3))) # (1, 0), (1, 0) adds zeros to top and left
m.add(CornerConv2D(5)) # Valid padding as default

m.compile(loss='mse', optimizer="adam")

m.summary()
input_test = np.random.random((9,9,3))
pred = m.predict(input_test.reshape(1,9,9,3))

print(pred.shape)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213013/discussion-on-answer-by-lowry-change-the-shape-of-a-kernel-of-a-convolution-laye).